# How to make user interface that connects to back-end

Tags: django, python-3.x, user-interface, web-applications, server

I am in the process of building some machines/devices (you could think of them as kiosk like info devices with touchscreen and interface)

I am thinking about what the best way would be to write the code for the machine but I just don’t have enough experience and there seems to be so many options.

The underlying processes that have to be executed are now written in python (3.6). Python is not absolutely needed, so I could also rewrite it in a different language. My idea for now was to make an GUI with PyQT or Tkinter and run that locally on the machines.

The problem with that idea for now is that:

1. the machines will be deployed so I need remote access to them
2. It seems to be not be the best solutions to use python for the GUI.

What I would prefer would be to have a server running from my office to which the machines all connect to. The server should run the underlaying processes and probably create a response page on the machines (?). What would be needed for this? A server running ubuntu server and Django with python, css, js and html? Or PHP or node.js. All I know for sure is that the software needs to be able to communicate and exchange input and output from the front-end to the back-end.

What would be the best solution here?

Comment: This question is too broad. There are many, many ways to accomplish what you are asking.

Comment: Okay, I see. I have read more about it and am now leaning towards an LAMP setup with linux, apache, mysql and php. This would be one of the possible setups to use right?